# Linker errors with AWS library

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode8, aws-sdk, aws-mobilehub

I'm trying to integrate AWS to my existing ios project and I'm getting "ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64" error and a bunch of linker errors like "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput, referenced from: objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSPushManager.o)". I followed a tutorial from integration page from Mobilehub. Anyone know how to resolve this issue?